# Is there a way to get out of Bullworth Academy?

Tags: bully

I found the hole near the Library building and the detention zone. There is a door and a keypad here. I used the keypad and my character guessed the code, but it won't open. Do I need a key? I also tried some weapons to see it would fall down, but that didn't work either.

[image]

Comment: What point are you at in the story? That door has something to do with an event later in the game.

Comment: Do you mean a mission or a story?

Comment: What chapter are you on is what I meant @Yamadan506

Comment: I'm on Chapter 1, is this door restricted till the next chapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular door is used late in the game during Chapter IV

> during the mission Stronghold Assault where Jimmy is tasked with attacking the nerd's "stronghold", the observatory to confront the nerd's leader Earnest.

You are however able to leave the campus officially after you complete chapter I where they open the gates to the front of the school.

Comment: What is a mission called Stronghold Assault?

Comment: Missions are just the jobs and such you are doing for people around the school to progress the story.

Comment: I do not mean what is a mission I mean what is Stronghold Assault?

Comment: It's just a mission that takes place during chapter 4, I'm not going to go into any details to prevent spoilers.

Comment: @Yamadan506 I added a bit more information in the spoiler if you care to look.

Comment: Stronghold = a type of fortification (Keep, Castle, Citadel are types of fortifications). Alternatively, "base". Essentially Stronghold Assault = attacking a base